How should I come up with a power supply for 5 motors, one micro-controller (ESP32) and one microprocessor (Jetson Nano) for an object sorting arm
I am trying to design a power supply for a robotic arm with 5 servo motors(2 are MG90S and 3 1501MG motors). I'm planning to use an ESP32 microcontroller and Jetson Nano.
I have the option of using several buck converters for each motor or coming up with a power supply with AC mains input and the seven required outputs.  Which SMPS topology would be suitable for the design idea I've got in mind? And if it's not suitable, what other approach should I consider?

Just follow the eval schematics
